# Import error no module named OAuth python twitter feed

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to write a small twitterbot in python for my rasppi. I have updated my requests, updated python, removed and re-installed the existing oauth package and still get the following error:
`ImportError: No module named requests_oauthlib`

Can anyone help please? My .py code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import random
from twython import Twython
CONSUMER_KEY = 'Your-Consumer-Key'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'Your-Secret-Key'
ACCESS_KEY = 'Your-Access-Key'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'Your-Access-Secret'

api = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET) 

api.update_status(status=sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Please, try to improve your question by adding some code. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add it to the question. Use the `edit` button below the tags.

Comment: thank you mcNets. Apologies!

Comment: How did you install the package?

Comment: Hello - I removed and re-installed. To remove: `sudo apt-get remove python-oauthlib`. To install: `pip install oauthlib -U`

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this different lib you need to install? https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib